# Open URL from command line with default input using MacOS

Tags: macos, open

What I try to do is 
1. MacOS terminal, I will input command line like below

> open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'http://translate.google.com' --input "myWebInput"

2. I am expecting it returns an opened URL, with my input ready in the input box, and the translation is ready there

Comment: Thanks jimtut, you are correct, I edited a little bit and it is works.   >/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=gracias'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Chrome is your default browser, you don't even need the "-a" argument part.  Just do something like this:

```
open https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=gracias
```

In this case, "gracias" is your input, so jut adjust as needed.  You're welcome!

Comment: As you suggested, I tried and it works.  Thanks very much Jimtut.  >/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=gracias'

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please press the "check mark" on this answer to accept it.

Comment: checked, not very familiar yet, will get used to it ;)